# Notification Center notifications do not change to "read" status

Tags: bug, global-inbox, safari

When I get a notification in my inbox in the last few days, I've seen that it won't clear to "read" status after, and the badge will stay on it, unless I select "mark all as read".  Notice in the screenshot below I have one not grayed out; it won't turn gray (and remove the badge) even if I click on it, even across multiple sites visited.  This occurs even with extensions turned off, so I don't believe it's ad-blocker related.

[image]

Mac OS 12.4 (Monterrey), Safari 15.5

Comment: @F1Krazy No, that doesn't... my point is that I can't mark them as read other than by selecting "mark all as read", I can't imagine they're not intended to turn to read once I've selected them, are they??

Comment: It was the same for me, and "fixed" after clearing local cache with hard refresh, now it's working as expected. My assumption is that it's something they initially forgot, and added in later "patch" that the browser didn't load.

Comment: Anyway, as clearly stated in the announcement, we should report bugs there so closing this one.

Comment: Ok, slight clarification, hitting the "mail" icon does mark them individually, but if I click on the notification to bring up the question/answer/etc it's notifying me of, it doesn't mark as read - that's the functionality that I very much hope is not working [and is not [tag:working-as-deisnged]...]

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Fair enough.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how it was for me.